# Usar vozes do conversor de texto e fala do windows em javascript e nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reconhecimento-de-voz

Alguém sabe como usa o conversor de texto e fala do windows no javascript ou node js?
tem que ser necessariamente do windows ..

Comment: Você se refere a Speech to Text ou Text to Speech?

Comment: ambos vc sabe de algum dos 2 que eu possa estar utilizando com node.js ou javascript ?